# How to use an XML schema for de/serialization of a custom Claim.ValueType in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, xsd, claims-based-identity

I'm considering refactoring the authentication and authorization process for all the applications I have worked on in my current position in the last 2 years, since I'm quite fed of writing what is essentially the same Admin panel over and over for every application; I was thinking about a centralized user management webapp that will provide claims for all the other apps in the ecosystem: .NET Desktop, ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core.

Considering the variety of apps, those Claims should include at least:

- the application domain name (the same user can have access to differen apps)
- a role for that application (the same user can be Admin of an app but simple user of another app)
- a collection of groups the user can have read access to (one collection for each application domain)
- a collection of groups the user can have write access to (one collection for each application domain)

Now, the [offical documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.claims.claim.valuetype?view=netcore-2.1) on the `Claim.ValueType` states this:

> If your solution requires complex value types, it is recommended that you use standard XML schema types in the ValueType property to indicate how the Value property is meant to be serialized and deserialized from a string

Let's suppose I successfully create an XML schema (never done before, that's something I'm working on) and I'm about to create the Claim using this overloaded constructor method:

```
public Claim (string type, string value, string valueType, string issuer);
```

again, the .NET API says that

> The Type property is a string (typically a URI) that contains the semantic information about the claim; it tells you what the value of the claim means. For example, a claim with a claim type of GivenName ("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/givenname") represents a user's first name. The value of the Type property can be one of the well-known claim types defined in the ClaimTypes class, or it can be an arbitrary URI as defined by the issuer. For example, a claim type of "urn:spendinglimit" might represent a user attribute which makes sense within the business context of the issuer.

Here is where I just can't pull all the strings together: how do I use that schema? I've read that the URI string can also just be an on-the-fly made-up string, but given that I'm writing a custom schema, should it contain some kind of reference for **actually** creating the Claim? If that's the case, how do I transform a real file in something that doesn't seem to point to really anything (I tried to go after all those URIs for built-in types, all blanks)? How is this schema helping in storing the Claims, or - at this point confusion level is very high - how do I store them?